# NoReverseMatch in Django (url ploblem)

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm a beginner of Django
I want to set my url with database field_name instead of use primary key from Django tutorial. This is my code.

```
*mysite*
**dwru/urls.py**
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('product.urls', namespace="product")),
]

*myapp*
**product/urls.py**
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
   url(r'^(?P<name_catalog>[-_\w]+)/$', views.product_list_from_index, name='catalog'),
]

**product/views.py**
def product_list_from_index(request, name_catalog):
   catalog = get_object_or_404(Catalog, name_catalog=name_catalog)
   context = {
   'catalog': catalog
}
   return render(request,'product/product_list.html', context)


**product/models.py**
class Catalog(models.Model):
  name_catalog = models.CharField(max_length=45)
  product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)

**template/product/index.html**
{% for catalog in catalog_list %}
    <h1><a href="{% url 'product:catalog' catalog.name_catalog %}">{{ catalog.name_catalog }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Then I add Catalog field with "TestCa01" then it shown an error

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'catalog' with arguments '(u'TestCa01',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'$(?P<name_catalog>[-_\\w]+)/$']
```

it kind of some problem with this line in template

```
{% url 'product:catalog' catalog.name_catalog %}
```

any Idea?

Comment: I use this [-_\w] but I don't know why error shown this one  [-_\\w].

Answer (score 0):

The `$` in your first url pattern *might* be the issue. The dollar sign indicates that it's the the end of the pattern, so it would never bother to include/check the product urls. Is the index url working?